# How to create a custom view without rectangular bounds, enabled for Gesture regocnition

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create custom views which might overlap rectangular boundaries. But as soon as I extends UIView to defined custom view. The gesture recognizer on last view added as subview to parent view is getting invoked.

I have used same rectangular boundary for both the custom view, but drawing different area within.

[image: Sample Polygon views with overlapping rectangle boundaries]

```
public class PolyGonUIView : UIView {
    var pointsArray : [CGPoint]!
    var name: String!

    init(_ name: String , _ size : Int,_  points : [CGPoint]) {
        let boundArea = CGRect(x:100, y:100, width: CGFloat(size), height: CGFloat(size))
        pointsArray = points
        self.name = name;
        super.init(frame: boundArea); -- This is what I want to avoid.
        var gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    public func handleTap (_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tapped me here " + name)
    }

    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let color:UIColor = UIColor.yellow
        let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bpath.move(to: pointsArray[0])
        for point in self.pointsArray {
            bpath.addLine(to: point)
        }
        bpath.lineWidth = 5.0
        bpath.close()
        color.set()
        bpath.fill()
        bpath.stroke()
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem. I mean I don't think you can draw a view without a x,y and width and height. So, you can't do that, so why are you coming up with this.

Answer (score 0):

A view is a rectangle. Nothing can change that fact. You can simulate a non-rectangular shape by override the `draw(_:)` method (as you already have). This will give the appearance of a non-rectangular view. But all events still go to the rectangle.

This can be solved by overriding the `hitTest(_:with:)` method of your view class. Your implementation should return `self` if the event happens within the desired shape of your view and it should return `nil` if the event happens outside the desired shape.

Comment: I have seen many apps which have similar overlapping blocks, Does it mean they are inside a same view and for each click they identify which exact component within the view have been clicked.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You can have overlapping, separate views for your hexagons as long as you override `hitTest` as I described. Or you could have one big view displaying all hexagons with one tap gesture and you simply do the calculations to determine which hexagon was actually tapped. Both approaches work.